# How to connect via ADO to remote MySQL without having to install ODBC driver?

Tags: mysql, odbc, ado

Is there any way to connect via ADO from a local Windows machine to a remote MySQL database *without* having to have a MySQL ODBC driver installed? I'm trying to connect from an Excel file, and when I have the driver installed it works just fine, of course. However, I would like to distribute the Excel file to my users, without making them install the driver. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If Excel does not have a built in connector for MySQL of some sort then no, you won't be able to do this without installing some sort of driver.